# how to Copy Values From 1dimensional array to 2dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

How do I copy data from 1d array to 2d array?

Suppose
there is an array namely `a[10000]` with values like
`[ 1,2,3,55,66,77,88, ... ... , 9999]`
values may be repeated ...

Now I want to convert this array which holds 10,000 values right now into 2 dimensional array
that has 100 rows and 100 columns.

After that
Is it possible to implement a `SELECTION SORT` on a 2 dimensional array?

Comment: is it a homework for you ,out of curiosity since we use to get this type of stuff at school but in C++

Comment: Yet Another Alternative is something involving `array_splice`.  Not an answer as I don't really have time right now and just wanted to throw it out there.

Answer (score 0):

Define two loops and do some multiplication

```
for ($i=0; $i< 100; $i++) {
  for ($j=0; $j< 100; $j++) {
    $twoDarray[$i][$j] = $oneDarray[$i*100 + $j];
  }
}
```

For sorting a multidimensional array you use array_multisort.
Here's the manual page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: That's not valid PHP.

Comment: Oh my god! Faster than me! :D

Comment: @AmalMurali You're right, but fixing it so it is could be an exercise for the OP.  The question probably *is* an exercise for the OP.

Comment: @vp_arth PHP requires $ signs as first character for variables. It is mandatory.

Comment: I know, but I see @Johan correct it, and now it's wrong again :)

Comment: It is but let me not complicate things. I'll edit it to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 0; $i<100; $i++)
{
    for($j = 0; $j<100; $j++)
    {
       $indice = $j + 100 * $i;
       $newArray[ $i ][ $j ] = $oldArray[ $indice ];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

assuming $a = array(1,2,3,4,5....1000)

```
$b = 0;
$c = 0;
foreach ($a as $new_number){
    if ($b < 100){
        $b ++;
    } else {
        $b = 1;
        $c ++;
    }
    $new_array[$c][$b] = $new_number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just more one variant:

```
foreach($a as $k=>$v){
 $b[(int)($k/100)][$k%100] = $v;
}
```